# How to use BLOB URI as a source in the Ansible module : azure_rm_image

Tags: azure, ansible

```
tasks:
    - name: Create custom image
      azure_rm_image:
        subscription_id: <>
        resource_group: <>
        location: <>
        name: <>
        source: "https://*****/vmdisk/template-centos-7-azure"
        os_type: Linux
```

I am facing the below error :

Azure Error: BadRequest\nMessage: OSDisk doesn't have a valid source (none of the snapshot or blobUri or managedDisk is set)."}

Answer (score 1):

Ansible documentation says that parameter **source** in Ansible playbook azure_rm_image can be be a virtual machine, **OS disk blob URI**, managed OS disk, or OS snapshot.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_image_module.html

**OS disk blob URI** should have .vhd extension. Here is a link to Ansible azure module source code
https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/blob/2d8e96d8b9b99bf01c0cb7eee8e2c8e37ea8d1d3/plugins/modules/azure_rm_image.py#L231

Try to add .vhd extension at the end of your disk Blob URI.